# Why add parentheses around a process name?

Tags: process, systemd

On my machine ([Debian testing](http://www.debian.org/releases/testing/)), when I do

```
ps aux | grep pam
```

I obtain

```
orto        609  0.0  0.0  58532  2148 ?        S    08:06   0:00 (sd-pam)  
orto       5533  0.0  0.0  12724  1948 pts/1    S+   16:51   0:00 grep pam
```

`(sd-pam)` seems a strange name for a process. Reading this [forum](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.arch.general/51350), I see that this name is set on purpose by systemd. In the [source code](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/tree/src/core/execute.c#n809) we see

```
/* The child's job is to reset the PAM session on
 * termination */

/* This string must fit in 10 chars (i.e. the length
 * of "/sbin/init"), to look pretty in /bin/ps */
rename_process("(sd-pam)");
```

What does it mean look pretty in `/bin/ps` and why to choose `(sd-pam)` and not just `sd-pam` as a name? Putting parenthesis around the name seems indicate that this process has something special like for a kernel thread e.g. `[kintegrityd]`.

Comment: What do you mean with "what is the purpose of doing this"? It's a name, it possibly just resembles what it does (SessionDestroy-PAM?).

Comment: I 've modified my question taking your remark into account.

Comment: Ah apologies, I didn't understood you were talking about the parenthesis. Honestly I don't know: according to [this](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch38_07.htm) `ps` encloses the accounting name of the process into parenthesis and prints that if the process to be shown has been renamed of if `ps` is not able to find the process by its original name anymore, however this of course doesn't explain why this is done in `pam`'s source code, which has nothing to do with `ps`.

Comment: The "to look pretty" on the other hand probably refers to the fact that using at most 10 characters the process' line in `ps` will fit a typical 80-characters-wide TTY

Comment: Maybe I read the comment by @kos sub-consciously, but I was just about to say it's probably to avoid people looking in vain for a binary called sd-pam.  After reading that ps already uses the exact same syntax, that may well be deliberate.  Certainly there would be other process listing tools that don't add the brackets.  (`systemd-cgls`?)

Comment: @kos: "sd" very likely stands for systemd, not for "session destroy".

Comment: @intelfx Indeed, it was just the fist thing that came on my mind, I didn't meant it to be serious.

Comment: How do I kill such a process?

Answer (score 20):

> Putting parenthesis around the name seems indicate that this process has something special

There are two cases:

- `(...)`

> When PID 1 starts a service binary it will first fork off a process,
>   then adjust the process' parameters according to the service config
>   and finally invoke execve() to execute the actual service process. In
>   the time between the fork and the exec, we use PR_SET_NAME to change
>   the process' name to what is going to be started, to make it easy to
>   map this to the eventual service started. Note however, that there's a
>   strict size limit on he "comm" name (i.e. the process name that my be
>   set with PR_SET_NAME, i.e. the one "top" shows), which means we have
>   to truncate. We chop off the beginning of the string, since usually
>   the suffix is more interesting (otherwise, all of systemd's various
>   services would appears as "(systemd-)" – which isn't particularly
>   useful). We enclose the name in (), in order to clarify that this is
>   the process that is going to become the specified process eventually,
>   but isn't it yet.

See https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2016-April/036322.html

- `(sd-pam)` is the special case

> If we spawn a unit with a non-empty 'PAMName=', we fork off a
>       child-process *inside* the unit, known as '(sd-pam)', which watches the
>       session. It waits for the main-process to exit and then finishes it via
>       pam_close_session(3).

Comment: worth mentioning there are also `[...]` brackets for kernel threads and kernel modules

Answer (score 6):

> What does it mean look pretty in /bin/ps and why to choose (sd-pam) and not just sd-pam as a name? Putting parenthesis around the name seems indicate that this process has something special

Yes, it has something special. This is a made-up name and *not* a name of any existing binary. In other words, there is no "sd-pam" file anywhere; this process is a fork of PID 1.

Parentheses are probably meant to indicate this.

Comment: Do you know if there is other processes using the same convention and if this is a standard convention?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni: I'm not aware of any convention for naming such processes. However, this does not mean that there are no conventions.