What is "p-portal" I saw in System Monitor in Linux on several occasions?
Looking at the following screen shot from System Monitor in Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (Linux 4.15.0-1079-oem), you see "(p-portal)" in the process list:

I should have interrogated systemctl, ps and the like while it was up, but was busy on other things and mentally cataloged it for later follow-up. However, I cannot catch it up again! I cannot find it using DuckDuck, Bing or Google search.
I thought it was perhaps associated with Chrome, which I had open at the time, but haven't seen it again with or without Chrome up. I had installed some Perl modules recently (Moo,Text-Template-1.61, Parallel-ForkManager-2.02), but didn't find it among the source files there.
It doesn't appear in the output of systemctl list-unit-files at other times (as I said, I didn't check while it was visible in system monitor), nor output of pstree nor output from ps combined with xlsclients per the answer at How to list all running daemons?
I would appreciate hearing if anyone has encountered this process "p-portal" and knows what it is/does.

Hope this helps  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278876/540130

Parenthesis enclosed names:
When systemd starts a process it first forks off a process,
then adjusts the process' parameters according to the service config
and finally invokes execve() to execute the actual service process.
In the time between the fork and the exec, the process may have a name in parenthesis (like (sd-pam) or (p-portal)).

The parentheses indicate that the command overwrote its name, or that ps could not find the name, and that ps is printing instead the "accounting name."
~From milk.ua

Note however, that there's a
strict size limit on he "comm" name (i.e. the process name that my be
set with PR_SET_NAME, i.e. the one "top" shows), which means we have
to truncate.
Truncating the comm name:
We chop off the beginning of the string, since usually
the suffix is more interesting (otherwise, all of systemd's various
services would appears as "(systemd-)" – which isn't particularly
useful). We enclose the name in (), in order to clarify that this is
the process that is going to become the specified process eventually,
but isn't it yet.
Take a look at systemd documentation.
What is (sd-pam)
It is actually a fork process of PID 1 and is set manually by systemd, there is no "sd-pam" executable file anywhere.
What is (p-portal)
It is probably the chopped off ending of the process xdg-desktop-portal that is eventually gonna be xdg-desktop-portal but currently it's (p-portal).

I am fairly satisfied that is what happened with p-portal after your explanation and hyperlink to Poettering's 2016 post about using PR_SET_NAME and enclosing in parentheses to signal the process is in, well, process of becoming as it were. I note that pstree still displays "(sd-pam)" though. I had his 2010 blog systemd for Administrators, Part II, but he didn't mention the parentheses, though discussed PR_SETNAME and processes changing their names (hence systemd putting spawned processes in a cgroup so they can't completely hide).
